# Is the risk-reward ratio considered in Quantitative Finance?

Tags: risk

Many discretionary traders swear by risk-reward ratio, as in "The minimum risk-reward ratio for a Forex trade is 1:2."

Do quantative traders use risk-to-reward ratio as well? If so, how do you calculate the minimum risk-reward ratio?

Comment: Do you know what the [Sharpe ratio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sharpe_ratio) is?

Comment: Quants do not care about risk-reward, its not part of their job description. Strategists and traders do.

Comment: @Matt Wolf By traders, you mean discretionary traders, not quantative traders?

Comment: @TomTucker, with traders I mean anyone who takes and manages risk, someone who signs responsible for profits and losses.

Comment: @Matt Wolf I edited the question as I was referring to quantative traders.

Comment: @MattWolf Not sure how you define "Quants", but it seems to me that this is at the heart of our field.

Comment: @Shane, I guess I had a specific sub-group in mind when I said quants do not engage in risk/reward considerations. For me "quants" rarely should be tasked with risk-return considerations because most severely lack real trading and risk management experience. You can't say you fulfill your fiduciary duty to clients and at the same time put billions at risk off the back of theoretical concepts and historically tested ideas and strategies. Banks and hedge funds are generally very good at segregating who thinks about risk/reward and who performs mathematical/statistical analysis...

Comment: @MattWolf, perhaps in this case “virtue lies in the middle ground". My view is that most quants will definitely benefit from a higher exposure to real markets behavior and real trading experiences. Similarly, for most traders developing quantitative skills can be really useful in their day-to-day work.

Comment: @sets, no question, I holeheartedly agree. But when you leave real risk and rewards in the hands of those with very little to no risk taking and managing experience due to an over-reliance on academic theories you end up with something like all current global central banks = blown out of any feasible proportion balance sheets and a gamble-like experiment that nobody understands nor risks to estimate the outcome of. Same stories goes with uncountable "quant desks" that blew up because of lack of risk management experience and over-reliance on models.Model risk is the most underpriced risk today

Comment: My whole point is that quants should do what they do best, test out theories, develop models and by all means, work closely with traders and other risk takers to fully understand the repercussions when models eventually blow up or correlations break down. Strictly speaking an algorithmic trading strategy should not concern itself at all with risk-reward in the portfolio sense but it should generate trading signals based on the model intrinsic risk-reward characteristics. Whether signals are taken, how orders are sized, how pre-trade risk correlates with open positions should be left to traders

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maximizing expected return while minimizing risk is at the heart of the quantitative revolution in finance in [modern portfolio theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modern_portfolio_theory).

Starting with Harry Markowitz (1952) ["Portfolio Selection"](http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/2975974?uid=2&uid=4&sid=21102880396707), a huge portion of quantitative finance is dedicated to refining the ideas around mean-variance portfolio optimization.  The objective is to find a weight vector $w$ that will minimize:

$$w^T \Sigma w$$

subject to:

$$R^T w = \mu$$

When evaluating performance, [the Sharpe ratio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sharpe_ratio) is the most widely used performance measure, and it directly (if a little crude) addresses the trade-off between risk and reward.

$$S = \frac{E[R-R_f]}{\sqrt{\mathrm{var}[R]}}$$

I recommend reading Peter Bernstein's ["Capital Ideas"](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471731749) as a gentle introduction to this subject.

Comment: if this is "quant" to you then what is not? Portfolio selection and Modern Portfolio Theory (MPT) lies pretty much at the heart of any discretionary and on-fundamentals focused portfolio manager. I guess knowledge of MPT is most likely tested in one of the first interview questions of any junior starting out in the traditional buy-side industry.

Comment: @MattWolf well as surprising as it might sound, you will find a lot of finance professionals who can't write down these "equations". You might consider a lot of people as non-quants for you because of your background and line of work but I'm pretty sure you'd be surprised how quickly you can be considered as a quant in some companies.

Comment: @SRXX, fair point which is why I qualified my comment in response to the question above in that it reflects just my opinion and not necessarily a universal view. It is just that I find the term "quant" in general quite overrated. I do not consider myself a quant because I lack a rigorous mathematical and/or statistical background.